# Python django module does not define attribute error, but the attribute is there in the code

Tags: python, django

I get the following error when trying to build a migration in django 1.6.8:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.template.loaders.app_directories" does not define a "Loader" attribute/class
```

I'm running the migration with the command:

```
django-admin.py migrate cms_page --settings=path.to.settings
```

I've checked `django.templates.loads.app_diretories` and it does in fact define the class `Loader`  class.

I don't know where to start looking to debug this. I can post additional output, settings etc, whatever's useful but I don't want to start with five hundred lines of settings and backtrace!

Template loader:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
```

Comment: paste your TEMPLATE_LOADERS from settings.py here

Comment: Try
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', (
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    )),
)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Incorrect version of django-debug-toolbar was eventually to blame.